# Regex with ng-if

Tags: regex, angularjs

```
  <div class="row" ng-if="MyTest.Item.MyPassword != MyTest.Item.ConfirmPassword">
       <div class="col-md-12">
      <p class="red-color"> Password must be between 4 and 8 digits long and include at least one numeric digit And Passwords must match! </p>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I need to show the above message when "Mypassword != ConfirmPassword" and the regex '/^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$/' is not fulfilled with the password field.How can I use regex with ng-if ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

On your view:

```
ng-if="isValid()"
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.isValid = function(){
   return MyTest.Item.MyPassword == MyTest.Item.ConfirmPassword 
          && yourRegexp.test(MyTest.Item.MyPassword);
}
```

Comment: How can we call a function within a ng-if ? it should be a boolean value no ?

Comment: @Sampath, yes. But my **isValid()** function returns boolean value too.
See the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/JuS7W/

Comment: This isn't great practice.  That function isValid will be called infinitely. Thus performance suffers.

Answer (score 0):

In your input field, add your required pattern.

```
<input type="password" ng-model="MyTest.Item.MyPassword" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$/"/>
```

This will ensure `$valid` of your form is true

and in your `div` add additional condition:

```
ng-if="MyTest.Item.MyPassword != MyTest.Item.ConfirmPassword && myForm.$invalid"
```